remove multiple attribute from chosen select jquery
I have a dropdown with chosen select plugin
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ML.AccountID, Model.Accounts, new { id = "ddl_account", @class = "form-control form-control-sm chosen-select", @multiple = true })

Via jquery I want to make it single select or multi select based on some value
if (element_text.includes('a')) {
     $("#ddl_account").removeAttr("multiple").trigger('chosen:updated');
          }
else {
      $("#ddl_account").attr("multiple", true).trigger('chosen:updated');
          }

But it does not make any difference , if the element_text contain a , it will still be multiselect dropdown , although in inspect window, multiple attribute has been removed.
I also tried with prop
if (element_text.includes('a')) {
     $("#ddl_account").prop("multiple", false).trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
else {
     $("#ddl_account").prop("multiple", true).trigger('chosen:updated');
     }

How can I switch chosen select from single to multiple and vice versa ?
Jquery version is 3.3.1

Have you tried @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ML.AccountID, Model.Accounts, new { id = "ddl_account", @class = "form-control form-control-sm chosen-select", @multiple = false }) ?

@LajosArpad  Let me clarify , there is another dropdown, upon changing its value (if value is a than we need to make dropdown ddl_account as single select otherwise multiselect)

A workaround to do that is first destroy the existing Chosen instance, then Update the <select> element to be either single or multiple select based on your condition, and after that re-initialize Chosen to reflect the changes
function toggleDropdown(element_text) {
    var $select = $("#ddl_account");

    $select.chosen('destroy');

    if (element_text.includes('a')) {
        $select.prop("multiple", false);
    } else {
        $select.prop("multiple", true);
    }

    $select.chosen({
        width: "100%",
        disable_search_threshold: 10
    });
}

toggleDropdown(someTextVariable);


You should be able to toggle the property value between true and false. The method includes() returns a boolean and you can use that directly to set the boolean value of the multiple property on the select element.
Her is a vanilla JavaScript example:


let element_text = "Test string including an a";

document.forms.form01.ddl_account.multiple = !element_text.includes('a');
<form name="form01">
  <select name="ddl_account" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>



And here the jQuery version:


let element_text = "Test string including an a";

$("[name='ddl_account']")
  .prop("multiple", !element_text.includes('a'));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form01">
  <select name="ddl_account" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>




it does not worked on chosen select plugin

So, a plugin that breaks standard functionality -- that is ridiculous. Hopefully my answer can help somebody that doesn't use that plugin then.

Just to update , We have to re initialize select chosen as shown in answer by Mina. And its not ridiculous as its a javascript standrad way
